# Ruby on Rails Dynamic forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a week model (has_many days) and days model (belongs_to week), initially I generate a form that has 7 days.

Each day has some inputs (class name and description), I want to add a feature where user can add more lass name and descriptions dynamically. Do I need to create another model to hold these attributes or there is another way to handle that?

I was thinking about using cocoon and  just add days dynamically. Any recommendations?
I use rails 4 and ruby 2.

Comment: If you have access to, this one is a great screencast covering this topic: http://railscasts.com/episodes/403-dynamic-forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want each day to be able to have multiple descriptions and multiple class names then the easiest way is to have a model for description and a model for class name:

```
class Week < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :days
end

class Day < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :week
  has_many :descriptions
  has_many :class_names
end

class Description < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :day
end

class ClassName < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :day
end
```

Comment: how do I group them? So if I add new description, I add new class name as well?

Comment: you could have the description be a property of the class name or have the class name be a property of the description.  It might be best at this point to do some thinking about your db schema.  Have you done anything with relational databases before?

Comment: Yes, I have, not on this scale though. It will be a good practice. Thanks for your suggestions.